# Deletion of Apple Calendar event though Applescript

Tags: calendar, applescript

I am trying to delete a specific calendar event in Apple's build-in calendar app through an Applescript. I am able to locate the event but not able to delete it with the methods I have found.

The below script locates the event called `Test Event` and shows it in the Calendar app. It works fine.

```
set theStarttime to date "Wednesday, 18 April 2018 at 17.00.00"
set theEndtime to date "Wednesday, 18 April 2018 at 18.00.00"
set theSummary to "Test Event"

tell application "Calendar" to tell calendar "Privat"
    set theEventList to every event where its start date is greater than or equal to theStarttime
        and end date is less than or equal to theEndtime and summary is equal to theSummary
    set theEvent to first item of theEventList
    show theEvent
end tell
```

If I try to delete the event instead of showing it by changing the line `show theEvent` to `delete theEvent`, the event is still in the calendar app after the script is executed. However, it seems like it is deleted somehow, as the script can not locate the event anymore.

How can I delete the event from my calendar?

Answer (score 0):

`delete` is correct but you have to `save` the calendar. I added an `if` condition which avoids an error if the event could not be found.

```
tell application "Calendar"
    tell calendar "Privat"
        set theEventList to every event where its start date ≥ theStarttime and end date ≤ theEndtime and summary is equal to theSummary
        if theEventList is not {} then
            set theEvent to first item of theEventList
            delete theEvent
        end if
    end tell
    save
end tell
```